# Pandas groupby.agg with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas data frame similar to this:

| name | sales | profit | profit_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 200 | 100 | True |
| Joe | 300 | 150 | False |
| Mark | 200 | 100 | True |
| Mark | 300 | 150 | True |
| Judy | 300 | 150 | False |

The actual data frame has 100 columns.

The idea is: I want to group by name, and aggregate all the columns. However, certain columns depend on a flag. In this case, `sales` will be aggregated no matter what, but `profit` should be included in the aggregation only if `profit_flag` is **True**.

It should look like this if we use `sum`:

| name | sales | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 500 | 100 |
| Judy | 300 | Nan |
| Mark | 500 | 250 |

Is there anyway I can do this from one line using `df.groupby('name').agg()`?

Right now I'm using:

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame()
grouped['sales'] = df.groupby('name').sales.sum()
grouped['profit'] = df[df.profit_flag].groupby('name').profit.sum()
```

I'm getting the correct result, but since the actual data frame has many more columns, I wanted to know if I could somehow write something like this to avoid the clutter:

```
grouped = df.groupby('name').agg({
          'sales': 'sum',
          'profit' 'sum' #if profit_flag })
```

Is this even possible or should I just group 'flag dependent columns' in separate statemetns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mask the values prior to aggregation:

```
(df.assign(profit=lambda d: d['profit'].where(d['profit_flag']))
   .groupby('name', as_index=False)[['sales', 'profit']].sum(min_count=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   name  sales  profit
0   Joe    500   100.0
1  Judy    300     NaN
2  Mark    500   250.0
```

Comment: Without selecting column, you can `pop('profit_flag')`: `df.assign(profit=lambda x: x['profit'].where(x.pop('profit_flag'))).groupby('name').sum(min_count=1)`

Comment: @Corralien yes, but I don't like to mutate the input when generating a different DataFrame ;)

Comment: OK I understand but in this case, you don't need `lambda`: `df.assign(profit=df['profit'].where(df['profit_flag'])).groupby('name', as_index=False)[['sales', 'profit']].sum(min_count=1)`? Why reevaluate the dataframe?

Comment: Also true but it's a good habit and doesn't hurt ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably assign all flag-dependent columns in one statement, then use `.agg` to aggregate all the columns in another statement.

Comment: @mozway Some columns have '%' in the name, how can I use it in `df.assign`? using quotes gives an error

Comment: Use `.assign(**{'name with %': ...})`